# What is the best practice for running multiple background tasks

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I have a Windows Service (.NET 4.5.2) which should run multiple tasks in the background while I want to use the System.Threading.Tasks which of the following implementation you are considering best practice? Or am I completely wrong?

**Scenario 1:**

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Assume all tasks implemented the same way.
    // I believe we shouldn't await the tasks in this scenario.
    var token = this._cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    this.RunTask1(token);
    this.RunTask2(token);
    this.RunTask3(token);
}

private async Task RunTask1(CancellationToken token)
{
    var telebot = new Telebot("SOMETHING");
    while( true )
    {
        // Some work...
        // I/O dependent task.
        var response  = await telebot.GetUpdatesAsync(cancellationToken: token);

        //
        // Some other work
        // maybe some database calls using EF async operators.
        //
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), token);
    }
}
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Assume all tasks implemented the same way.
    // I believe we shouldn't await the tasks in this scenario.
    var token = this._cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    this.RunTask1(token);
    this.RunTask2(token);
    this.RunTask3(token);
}

private void RunTask1(CancellationToken token)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var telebot = new Telebot("SOMETHING");
            while( true )
            {
                // Some work...
                // I/O dependent task.
                var response = await telebot.GetUpdatesAsync(cancellationToken: token);

                //
                // Some other work
                // may be some database calls using EF async operators.
                //
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), token);
            }
        }, token);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to assign returned task to private field for grateful dispose?

Comment: You can use Task.Run(() => doStuff("hello world")); instead of Task.Factory.StartNew()

Comment: @AvsenevSlava As far as I know, they are equal.

Comment: @SerG I believe the cancellation token can be used to end the tasks.

Comment: But task doesn't end instantly. And how about exceptions?

Comment: Correct, and you shouldn't end them too and I think this is why cancellation token is for. For the exceptions, the idea is that each task should handle the exceptions but I didn't write any logic there because my question is whether this approach for running tasks is good at all or are there any catches.

Comment: For `async-await` you must always use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25009215/1768303.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `async` method runs synchronously until the first `await`. After that it will run on a ThreadPool thread (unless there's a `SynchronizationContext`).

So, using `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run` is discouraged as it's trying to parallelize something which is mostly already parallel.

If, however, you have a substantial synchronous part it can be useful using `Task.Run` (which is preferable to `Task.Factory.StartNew`) to parallelize it, but you should do it when calling the method and not in the method itself.

So, "Scenario 1" is better than "Scenario 2".

I would though that you shouldn't fire and forget these operations. You should store the tasks, wait for them to complete and observe any exceptions inside them, for example:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    var token = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    _tasks.Add(RunTask1(token));
    _tasks.Add(RunTask2(token));
    _tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => RunTask3(token))); // assuming RunTask3 has a long synchronous part
}

List<Task> _tasks;

protected override void OnStop()
{
    _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    Task.WhenAll(_tasks).Wait();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume the second OnStart method is OnStop. In this case, do I gain anything by making the OnStop method async and use await Task.WhenAll(_tasks)?

Comment: @Mohammadreza Yes, OnStop. If you could really change it to be an async method and return a task then it would be great, but you can't change the signature because it's an override. Making it `async void` would be much worse.

Comment: Just to clarify, if I change the base class void OnStop() to Task OnStop() without async keyword then the classes inherit from the base class can make the method async. Am I correct?

Comment: @Mohammadreza yes. I just assumed that the base class is .Net's `ServiceBase` which you can't change.

Comment: It is. I just asked that out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot explain which is best one but here is how things work

in 1. scenario code till await keyword is executed by parent Thread i.e. main thread of application. So once execution await task execution completed thing handled by context which is saved i.e. main thread context.

in 2. scenario code it started running on thread which is created by Task Factory. here once execution await task execution completed things handled by parent i.e Thread created by Task Factory.

So in the first scenario is good if you want to post something to main thread mostly to UI of application. Second scenario is good if you want to run thing in background and doesnt need of parent context i.e. main thread or UI thread.